# Get authorized by FB and Gmail in Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, laravel-5, facebook-graph-api

In one of my projects, I have added the Facebook and Google+ login to my website. The website is an SPA app. The front end is an Angular app and the back end is Laravel 5.1. Login with Facebook and G+ is working perfectly in the front end.

But I'm not sure how can I do the authorization in the back end after the user has logged in using the FB or G+ authorization data. This is my first Laravel project.

Comment: Try to search for Satellizer | Token-based AngularJS Authentication

Comment: @LearningMode: Thanks, I'll check it

Comment: Try using https://github.com/laravel/socialite